# Odoo Product label prints only one variant attribute

Tags: product, odoo

Im trying to print product labels for the product variant , each variant has variant attributes like size and color. For me it only prints one variant attribute for each variant like only size or only color, any ideas how to print multipe?

There is a link to the image displaying my issue

http://s1.postimg.org/oopgmal67/product_label.png

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<lots>
    <lot-line type="fields" name="id">
        <code type="field" name="code"/>
        <product type="field" name="name"/>
        <variant type="field" name="attribute_value_ids.name"/>
        <price type="field" name="list_price"/>
        <ean13 type="field" name="ean13"/>
        <currency type="field" name="company_id.currency_id.name"/>
    </lot-line>
</lots>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

product_label.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <lots>
    <lot-line type="fields" name="id">
    <code type="field" name="default_code"/>
    <product type="field" name="name"/>
    <price type="field" name="list_price"/>
    <ean13 type="field" name="ean13"/>
    <company type="field" name="company_id.name"/>
    <currency type="field" name="company_id.currency_id.name"/>
    <attribute_value_ids type="zoom" name="attribute_value_ids">
        <attribute_value_ids_name type="field" name="name"/>
    </attribute_value_ids>
     </lot-line>
         </lots>
```

and u also need to some changes in product_label.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:variable name="initial_bottom_pos">0.1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="initial_left_pos">0.1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="height_increment">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="width_increment">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="frame_width">10.00cm</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="frame_height">3.6cm</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="number_columns">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="max_frames">8</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="lots"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lots">
    <document>
        <template pageSize="(10.00cm,3.60cm)"   leftMargin="0.2cm" rightMargin="0.2cm" topMargin="1.5cm" bottomMargin="0.0cm" title="Address list" author="Generated by SnippetBucket.com">
            <pageTemplate id="all">
                <pageGraphics/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="lot-line" mode="frames "/>
            </pageTemplate>
        </template>
        <stylesheet>
            <paraStyle name="nospace" fontName="Courier" fontSize="10" spaceBefore="0" spaceAfter="0"/>
            <blockTableStyle id="mytable">
                <blockBackground colorName="white" start="0,0" stop="0,0"/>
                <blockBackground colorName="lightgrey" start="1,0" stop="-1,0"/>
                <blockAlignment value="CENTER"/>
                <blockValign value="MIDDLE"/>
                <blockFont name="Helvetica-BoldOblique" size="10" start="0,0" stop="-1,0"/>
                <blockFont name="Helvetica" size="8" start="0,1" stop="-1,1"/>
                <lineStyle kind="GRID" colorName="black" tickness="1"/>
            </blockTableStyle>
        </stylesheet>
        <story>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="lot-line" mode="story"/>
        </story>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lot-line" mode="frames">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $max_frames + 1">
        <!-- <frame break-before="page"> -->
        <frame>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:value-of select="$frame_width"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="height">
                <xsl:value-of select="$frame_height"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="x1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$initial_left_pos + ((position()-1) mod $number_columns) * $width_increment"/>
                <xsl:text>cm</xsl:text> 
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="y1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$initial_bottom_pos - floor((position()-1) div $number_columns) * $height_increment"/>
                <xsl:text>cm</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </frame>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="pmaxChars" as="xs:integer" select="80"/>

<xsl:template match="lot-line" mode="story">
    <blockTable style="mytable" colWidths="7.20cm,2.2cm"  > 

    <tr>
            <td>



     <para style="nospace">Code:  <xsl:value-of select="code"/></para>
                    <para style="nospace">Price: <xsl:value-of select="price"/></para>
                </td>
                 // u need to copy this column on your file
                    <td>
                        <para style="nospace"><xsl:value-of select="substring(product, 1, pmaxChars)"/></para><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <para style="nospace"><xsl:apply-templates select="attribute_value_ids"/></para>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <barCode message="123456789">
                         <ean-13>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ean13" />
                         </ean-13>
                     </barCode> 
                      <para style="nospace"><xsl:value-of select="ean13"/></para> 
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </blockTable>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sir i have same issue, is it working well??? if yes, then how can i do it in custom module...???